# Next JS - Problem with reloading or direct dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I have a problem with NextJS, I have a few pages with dynamic routes, eg:

```
queries/[id].tsx
queries/index.tsx
```

Now in dev mode, it loads fine when I go to

```
https://localhost:3006/queries/1324
```

The problem is when I build it, I can't directly link to that url. I have to go into the homepage and click to it. Is there any way to solve this? I'm deploying to an azure static web app.

I've tried with exportPathMap, but the thing is we're generating a lot of queries, and I can't rebuild every time someone makes a new query.

Comment: `exportPathMap` allows you to specify which pages should be built & exported when exporting a static site, which means that no dynamic pages would be built on-demand. If you need these pages to be built on-demand as users visit them, and you can't or don't want to pre-generate a list of all queries so their pages can be built and exported as static html pages, then you need to ditch `exportPathMap` and look at `getServerSideProps` and run your site in SSR mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use NextJS function **getStaticProps** and **getStaticPaths** . This will solve your problem
[Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)